# What should the payload be for Android push notifications (GCM)

Tags: android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

From my understanding of the GCM documentation you basically send whatever data you want as the `data` field. Then the client receives it and is responsible for handling it and displaying it. Is this wrong? What if like on iOS I just wanted to send a bit of text and have it display? Is there a standard key to use or anything? I'm pretty certain I've been through all the documentation I can find and don't see anything like this.

Comment: I've re-read your question several times and I still don't get the point. Yes, the way you've described it is the way it works. If you want to show up just a piece of text, you can send it in just one message as far as it's not larger than 4Kb in size. Is that the point?

Comment: The point was what field in the payload do I send that as. In APNS if the `alert` field is string, that is the notification message. iOS handles and everything is done. In GCM/Android that is not the case. The app needs to process incoming notification and tell Android how to display it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you're right. There are no standard keys like in iOS, it's all up to you seeing as you're the one responsible for the notification management.

Basically, in your `BroadcastReceiver` you should write the code for displaying a [Notification](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html#SimpleNotification) in the status bar. Just parse your JSONObject from the recieved message and show whichever piece of text you may have set.